# Grok and MySQL - how to set a connection?

Tags: python, grok

According to this doc: http://grok.zope.org/documentation/how-to/grok-orm-with-storm when i want connect to database (sqlite) i should set something like thIS:  with correct path TO MY DB. 
How to set a connection with mysql?

Answer (score 1):

you can add the connection string like this:

For more information take a look here:

https://storm.canonical.com/Tutorial#Creating a database and the store

HTH Christian